# How is "or" being used in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The meaning of the following phrase is taken from from Google dictionary...

> Phrase:  not necessarily
>
> Meaning: (As a response) what has been said or suggested may not be true or unavoidable.

Does this sentence mean *what has been said or suggested may be unavoidable*, or *may **not** be unavoidable.* **Which one is correct?**

Comment: it may not be (true or unavoidable). _Unavoidable_ here has almost the same meaning as _true_: it is unavoidable means it will come true. If it is _not_ unavoidable or _not_ true, you can use _not necessarily_.

Comment: ... may not be [true or unavoidable].

Answer (score 1):

Here **or** is not disjunctive it means it may not be true or it may not be unavoidable, where unavoidable explains the word true. In this context **or** can be replaced with **that is**.

In other words it may not be [true or unavoidable].

Answer (score 1):

I assume OP is more concerned with the semantics and syntax of the definition itself, rather than the meaning of "Not necessarily" as a response usually meaning *"I disagree / What you said may be untrue"*.

> *What has been said or suggested may not be true or unavoidable.*
>    ...can be structurally represented as...
>    ***A is not B or C***

...which native speakers will almost always parse as...

***A is not (B or C)***
 (i.e. - A isn't B, and it isn't C either)

This is in contrast to mathematicians interpreting formulae, or computers interpreting program code, where (in the absence of brackets) the default interpretation would be...

***A is (not B) or C***
 (i.e. - either A isn't B, or it *is* C)

---

The principle as set out above still applies in OP's cited definition, where ***may [not] be*** replaces ***is [not]***. This just downgrades the assertion from certainty *("You are wrong")* to possibility *("You may be wrong")*.